# Bucle for no se ejecuta

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un programa que me muestre las identidades trigonométricas a partir de un ángulo que ingrese el usuario. El programa convierte el ángulo a radianes y realiza los cálculos. El valor de X es el ángulo en radianes, este lo calculo en la función `seno` y `coseno`; el problema es que en la función `coseno` no se ejecuta el `for` que realiza los cálculos. Puse un `cout` que imprimiera que *ENTRO AQUI* dentro del `for`, y al ejecutarlo no se imprime porque nunca entra y el resultado que imprime en `coseno` es de 0.
No tengo ni idea del cuál es el problema, ya que en la función de `seno` todo funciona perfecto y es casi el mismo proceso. Agradecería si pudieran ayudar a esta pobre principiante.

El código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
 float cargardatos();
 float seno(int);
 float coseno(int);
 float tangente(float, float);
 float cotangente(float);
 float secante(float);
 float cosecante(float);

 
int main (){
    int g=cargardatos();
    float sen=seno(g);
    float cos=coseno(g);
    float tan=tangente(sen,cos);
    float cot=cotangente(tan);
    float sec=secante(cos);
    float csc=cosecante(sen);
   
}

float cargardatos(){
    int g;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    cout<<"Ingrese un ángulo: ";
    cin>>g;
    //x=g*3.14159/180;
//  cout<<"x: "<<x<<endl;
    return g;
}

float seno(int g){
    float sen=0, x, term, num;
    int den;
    x=g*3.14159/180;
    for(int n; n<=4;n++){
        num=den=1;
        for(int i=1; i<=2*n+1;i++){
            num*=x;
            den*=i;
        }
        term=num/den;
        if(n%2==1){
            term*=(-1);
        }
        sen=sen+term;
    }
    cout<<"El seno es: "<<sen<<endl;
    return sen,x;
}
float coseno(int g){
    float  cos=0, x, term, num;
    int den;
        x=g*3.14159/180;
    for(int n; n<=4;n++){
        cout<<"ENTRO AQUÍ";
        num=den=1;
        for(int i=1; i<=(2*n);i++){
            num*=x;
            den*=i;
        }
        term=num/den;
        if(n%2==1){
            term*=(-1);
        }
        cos=cos+term;
    }
    cout<<"El Coseno es: "<<cos<<endl;
    return cos;
}
float tangente(float sen, float cos){
    float tan;
    tan=sen/cos;
    cout<<"La tangente es: "<<tan<<endl;
    return tan;
}
float cotangente(float tan){
    float cot;
    cot=1/tan;
    cout<<"La cotangente es: "<<cot<<endl;
    return cot;
}
float secante(float cos){
    float sec;
    sec=1/cos;
    cout<<"La secante es: "<<sec<<endl;
    return sec;
}
float cosecante(float sen){
    float csc;
    csc=1/sen;
    cout<<"La cosecante es: "<<csc<<endl;
    return csc;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor inicial de `n`?

Comment: Como en la función de seno no la inicialicé y funcionaba perfecto, pensé que no seria necesario inicializarla en 0

Comment: Cuando no inicializas una variable, puede que esta valga 0.... o puede que valga 32456, quién sabe! Hasta el momento de acceder a ella no lo vas a saber, puesto que puede tener un valor residual que haya en la memoria que se le ha asignado. Estoy seguro de que alguien podrá darte una explicación más técnica, pero mejor acostúmbrate a inicializar TODO lo que vayas a usar, que no cuesta casi nada y te ahorra muchos dolores de cabeza

Comment: @padaleiana debieras escribir una respuesta, no?

Comment: Muchas gracias! ;)
Efectivamente resolví el problema al inicializar la variable.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como se mencionó en los comentarios, el problema nada más fue que a la variable `n` en el `for` no se le asignó un valor inicial.
Como han dicho, asignar un valor inicial a las variables, siempre que sea necesario, ahorraría dolores de cabeza :)

---

No está demás mencionar lo escrito por *BenitoB*:

> Cuando no inicializas una variable, puede que esta valga 0.... o puede que valga 32456, quién sabe! Hasta el momento de acceder a ella no lo vas a saber, puesto que puede tener un valor residual que haya en la memoria que se le ha asignado. (...)

### Versión resumida, más clara

En [las respuestas de esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value), se menciona que si la variable tiene alcance global, su valor inicial será ***0***, y si tiene alcance local, será ***indeterminado***.

### Versión no tan resumida

Si se tiene en cuenta [este apartado de la documentación de C++ en el sitio de MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/initializers?view=msvc-160#zero-initialization), parte de él dice (énfasis mío):

> La inicialización cero es la configuración de una variable en un valor
> cero convertido implícitamente al tipo:
>
> - **Las variables numéricas se inicializan en 0 (o 0,0, 0,0000000000, etc.)**.

> La inicialización cero se realiza en distintos momentos:  (...)
>
> - Durante la inicialización del valor, para los tipos escalares (...)

y parte del ejemplo que se da es:

```cpp
int i0;              // inicialización cero a 0
```

En este [otro apartado de la documentación de C++](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/initializers?view=msvc-160#default-initialization), dice (de nuevo, énfasis mío):

> Las variables escalares se inicializan de forma predeterminada cuando
> se definen sin una expresión de inicialización. Tienen valores
> **indeterminados**.

Y se da como ejemplo:

```cpp
int i1;
float f;
char c;
```